# ViewPager and RecyclerView extrange behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` with a `ViewPager` which handles three `Fragment` s. The first of them contains a `RecyclerView`. Here is some code:

**FragmentViewPager**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player_view_pager, container, false);

    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.playerViewPager);
    adapterViewPager = new PlayerPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    return view;
}
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
// Returns the fragment to display for that page
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0: 
            return FirstFragment.newInstance("0", "Page # 1");
        case 1: 
            return SecondFragment.newInstance("1", "Page # 2");
        case 2: 
            return ThirdFragment.newInstance("2", "Page # 3");
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment**:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getActivity(), myList);

    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInUpAnimator(new OvershootInterpolator(1f)));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    loadData();

    return view;
}
```

And `loadData` method is an API call through `AsyncTask` which populates the adapter. This is the onPostExecute method:

```
myList = (ArrayList<>) result;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is when I first instantiate the `ViewPager` nothing is showed in the first `Fragment` even the API call and the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method are called. But if I scroll between the other Fragments and the `FirstFragment` is recreated by the `ViewPager`, then the data is shown.

Do you have any idea what is happening here?

Comment: try setting different fragment classes for each tab not just one fragment instances. i hope it will help

Comment: Sorry masoud, I had some errors in my question :) . I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting response update data myList (ArrayList<>) of FragmentAdapter, by any method created by you and then call notifyDataSetChanged() method of Adapter.

myList = (ArrayList<>) result;
This initialization is not reflect on FragmentAdapter ArrayList

Comment: Thanks! you are right :) . I changed the myList = (ArrayList<>) result; to myList.clear(); myList.adAll((ArrayList<Song>) result); and now it's working

Comment: @jos that's why I always make a base adapter class containing private final ArrayList<T>, and the adapter has setItems(List<T>) which clears inner list and uses addAll() on it. That way you can't mess up the data from outer code.

Answer (score 1):

```
adapterViewPager = new PlayerPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

You are already into a fragment, so you need to get that fragment instance of fragment manager.

Comment: Hi Florescu, thanks for your answer. I tried it, but same result :(

Comment: Look into your adapter. Does populate after api is responding?

Comment: The error was in the way that I was setting the list of the adapter. Take a look at the correct answer if you are interested. Thanks!